# Uploading multiple files using Python request over a REST API call

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am able to upload a single file using the following code:

```
import requests

notes = {'notes_pdf':'notes1.pdf','name':'notes_name1'}
url = "https://www.example.in/notes/api/v1/uploadNotes"

files = {'notes_pdf': open(notes['notes_pdf'], 'rb')}
response = requests.request("POST", url, params=querystring, files=files, data=notes)

return response.json()
```

Now, I want to send multiple files and the external REST API accepts the notes object in the following format.

```
multiple_notes = [{'notes_pdf':'notes1.pdf','name':'notes_name1'}, {'notes_pdf':'notes2.pdf','name':'notes_name2'}]
```

I am not able to send the object in such manner. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you noticed that there is an error in the `multiple_notes `. There are two quotes before ``notes_name1`` and  ``notes_name2``,  Probably it is not the problem. Could you edit yout question and add the error msg. Also, could you try to use
`multiple_notes 
 = json.dumps([{'notes_pdf':'notes1.pdf','name':'notes_name1'}, {'notes_pdf':'notes2.pdf','name':'notes_name2'}]) ` .To do so you will need `import json`

Comment: yes, that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. However, the problem is how to send multiple files in a particular format. The external API will try to get the uploaded in only like this - notes[0]['notes_pdf'], notes[1]['notes_pdf'] and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this API accepts same file object name?
If your API accepts a file names like `notes1.pdf` `notes2.pdf`, you can use the following code:

```
file_list = [note['notes_pdf'] for note in multiple_notes]  # get file name
files = {}
for file in file_list:
    files[file]=open(file, 'rb')
res = requests.post(url, files=files, ...)
```

Comment: No I have tried that. The API accepts file from the objects within the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `notes[0]['notes_pdf']` and  `notes[1]['notes_pdf']` as mentioned, then it should work:

```
multiple_notes = ({'notes_pdf':'notes1.pdf','name':'notes_name1'}, 
                  {'notes_pdf':'notes2.pdf','name':'notes_name2'})
```

According to the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) you can use tuples within the POST request.

Comment: so, should I request in the following manner: response = requests.request("POST", url, params=querystring, data=teste) ?

Without file parameter?